# Help me solving this question about Laplace transform.

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

If $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\bar{f}(s)$ then prove for $r>0$, $$ \mathcal{L}\{r^tf(at)\}=\frac{1}{s-\ln r}f\bigg(\frac{s-\ln r}{a}\bigg) $$

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: Start from the definition of the Laplace transform. Rewrite $r=e^{\ln r}$. Change variable.

Comment: Sir, I did that. But I was not able to that.